# Error mysqlconnect() max_users_connection

Tags: php, mysql

I have this site and its giving me a `max_users_connection` and i've read some document about this on the web where i need to make the value to `0` for unlimited and change value to something, but all that i need to do on the cPanel and go to `MySql Database` but i dont have an access to that, is there any way to resolve this without having to go to the cpanel, and below is the error im having

```
mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: User folderName already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections in /public_html/folderName/system/database/mysql.php on line 6
```

and on line 6, the code written there is

```
public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database){/*some function here*/}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to edit my.ini and change max_users_connection there. You can open it with any text editor. File is located in the mysql installation folder on your server.

file may also be called my_default*.ini. Just do a search for *.ini in your server folder.

if the line does not exist, just add max_users_connection = 0

Comment: i only one file which is `.ini` name `php.ini` include the code you told me too but not working.

Comment: alternatively look for my.cnf

Comment: i just checked, on 5.6 my file is called my-default.ini

mine does not have the line, so I can just add , after the [mysqld] line, 
max_users_connection = 0

Comment: alternatively you can run the query set global max_user_connections = 0. this is set per user, so make sure to run it for the php user
"GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myphpuser' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;"